# How to test a React Suspense 'promise wrapper' in Jest, when fetching data via axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jestjs, react-suspense

I'm trying to update my useAxios hook to work with React Suspense, following this guide:
https://deadsimplechat.com/blog/react-suspense/

```
const promiseWrapper = (promise: Promise<any>) => {
  let status = 'pending';
  let result: any;

  const suspender = promise.then(
    (value: any) => {
      status = 'success';
      result = value;
    },
    (error: any) => {
      status = 'error';
      result = error;
    }
  );

  return () => {
    switch (status) {
      case 'pending':
        throw suspender;
      case 'success':
        return result.data;
      case 'error':
        throw result;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown status');
    }
  };
};

export const useAxios = <T,>(requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig): T | null => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const doRequest = () => {
      const result = axios.request(requestConfig);
      setResponse(promiseWrapper(result));
    };

    doRequest(requestConfig);
  }, []);

  return response;
};
```

This 'promiseWrapper' pattern seems to be pretty common when using Suspense in react, with async calls.

I'm still wrapping my head around this, but here's my understanding of how it works...
We wrap our promise (the axios API call) in the promise wrapper, and then when the hook returns, it is returning the switch function that will return either return the data on success, throw the promise itself if its pending, and throws an error if there's an exception.

This all seems to work fine when I run the application, but I'm trying to write jest unit tests for when the useAxios hook returns an 'error' or is 'pending' and I cant get it to work.

For the error scenario, I have this jest test:

```
  it('should call endpoint and throw error on exception', async () => {
mockedAxios.request.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('error'));

expect(() => {
  renderHook(() => useAxios<TestResponseType>({}))
}).toThrowError();
});
```

But the error is never thrown. And I'm not sure how to mock the pending response at all.

Any pointers on how I can get these test cases passing?

Answer (score 1):

Test the custom hook with a dumb component, the `<Suspense/>` component and a `<ErrorBoundary/>` component.

E.g.

```
import { ErrorBoundary } from "react-error-boundary";
import { useAxios } from "./useAxios";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

describe('76404248', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const errorSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => { })
    const requestSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'request').mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('test error'))
    const TestComp = () => {
      useAxios({})
      return null;
    }
    render(
      <ErrorBoundary
        fallbackRender={({ error }) => <p>{error.message}</p>}
      >
        <Suspense fallback={<p>loading</p>}>
          <TestComp />
        </Suspense>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )

    expect(await screen.findByText(/test error/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    screen.debug();
    errorSpy.mockRestore();
    requestSpy.mockRestore();
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76404248/useAxios.test.tsx (17.177 s)
  76404248
    ✓ should pass (165 ms)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <p>
          test error
        </p>
      </div>
    </body>

      at logDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:82:13)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |   83.33 |       50 |   85.71 |   82.61 |                   
 useAxios.ts |   83.33 |       50 |   85.71 |   82.61 | 10-11,24,28       
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        18.565 s, estimated 23 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"react-error-boundary": "^4.0.9",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```